# When to use ~> in a Podfile

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm slowly coming around to using CocoaPods.

I'm confused as to when I should use the [~> operator](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod). Some libraries use it: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking, some don't: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController.

The only reason I can think of when you should use the ~> operator is when you are concerned a major upgrade will break your system. Is this the main reason?

Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted. The *motivation* for using ~> vs > etc is not only a valid question, but a possibly a critical one. I couldn't find any answers by reading the docs, so I asked on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Yes... ~> will not upgrade to major version.

Look full (and good) explanation here: http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html

Comment: Of course it will, depending on the version designated after ~>.

Comment: True, the guide we wrote should be enough to answer this question. If it isn't we're definitely appreciate a pull request.